# run android studio getting error

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have a problem with running Android Studio when starting a new project in android.

My Android Studio (in any version) is using Java, not Android, and it's not like any Android Studio I've seen.

when I click new project in this picture:

[image]

I see this:

[image]

and I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as the version of the android studio you are currently using, OS you are running on your system and others?

Comment: I run it on windows 10 64 bit, but Software version is no different, I tried it for version 2 and also version 3 but the result is same. and this problem is new from 2 or 3 days ago, I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: @SafooRa you can add images inline with your question instead of providing a link, which some people are hesitant to click without prior knowledge.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the Android plugin is disabled. You need to enable the plugin from `File -> Settings -> Plugins`. Then you need to enable all related to Android, it should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: so so so thank you, it worked, I really appreciate you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this as answer to close the question ;)